# Take the href from a trigger as background-img for another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, background-image

I'm absolutely no jquery-ninja and I'm new to stackoverflow, please be kind ^-^

I want a div with changing background-images. The first background-img is generated by jquery. It takes the first `ul li a`'s href and puts it in the background. This is working fine so far.

Now the tricky part: I want to change this background-img depending on the trigger's href. That means if I mouseover the second `ul li a` in my list, it should load "trigger-url-2" as background-img of div#gallery...and so on.

Here's my simplified code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="trigger-url-1">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="trigger-url-2">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="trigger-url-3">Name</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="gallery">Content</div>
```

And the jquery (it says the first `ul li a`'s href is loaded as div#gallery's background-img...seems to work fine)

```
var firstimage = $("ul li a").attr( "href" );
$("#gallery").css('background', 'url("'+firstimage+'") no-repeat left top');
```

I tried a lot of versions, but everytime it loads only the first trigger-href in my div#gallery. I also tried another $var, but nothing goes right. Here's one example:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(i, v) {
    $("ul li a").mouseover(function() {
    $("#gallery").css('background', 'url(("ul li a").attr("src")) no-repeat left top');
})
```

Can anyone help me? It' a strange and tricky request for a wordpress-gallery, that's why it has to be dynamic .__.

Thanky you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul li a').mouseover(function() {
    $("#gallery").css('background', 'url(' + this.href + ') no-repeat left top');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4zfPp/

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

```
$("ul li a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $("#gallery").css("background", "url(" + $(this).prop("href") + ") no-repeat left top");
});
```

should work for you I think. Binding via "on" applies it to every element in the selector.